# How to disable Import option in LibreOffice Calc while pasting text in a cell?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, pdf, copy-and-paste

I'm making a table in which I have to copy few lines from pdf to a table. I'm using LibreOffice calc for table making purpose. Problem is that even though I am copying simple text from the pdf, when I paste it to LibreOffice, Import Option keeps on poping up(randomly-sometimes it pop up sometime it does't). And due to this pasted text's font size also very small. Desired result is that when I paste the text in the cell, it just got pasted in the cell, without any time wasting popup which also disturbs the font size.
Same question is asked here but no solution.
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1813/disable-the-import-options-dialog/

Comment: Did you try "Paste Special"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple app for making Question answer pair table that could be exported in csv format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133464/simple-app-for-making-question-answer-pair-table-that-could-be-exported-in-csv-f) - The solution has been given in that question.

Comment: on mac, option+shift+ctl+v pastes unformatted text without dialog box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option to disable the dialog. LibreOfice Calc makes some decisions on the paste based on the type of text that is in the clipboard.

- If it is single line plain text, the content is directly pasted. If it is multi-line plain text, the text import dialog, such as you describe, appears.
- If it is formatted text, the "Select language to Use for Import" appears. Text will be pasted with a different formatting, deduced from the format information in the clipboard. Separate lines will be pasted in different cells, with formatting determined by the copied source text.

This is at times annoying behavior indeed. For repetitive work, one would prefer to set paste options for the session once, and then not be bothered anymore with dialogs and unexpected formatting of pasted content.

To import the text without breaking up the lines, disable all settings in the dialog. Next time you paste, the dialog will appear again, but settings are remembered. So it just takes the extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard to paste.

The text font of unformatted pasted text adopts to the current settings of the cells you are pasting in. You may want to either format the cells manually, or format the cells were you are going to paste with different font settings, or change the default font size of the spreadsheet by changing its "Default" style.