# Simple app for making Question answer pair table that could be exported in csv format?

Tags: libreoffice, gnumeric

I tried Libreoffice, but its Import option while pasting in the cell is very  annoying.I also tried Gnumeric but I am not able to paste using middle button.Parcellite to make copy paste faster and middle button pasting is not working with Gnumeric.
Is there any simple table maker app available that can accept only simple unformatted text? All these software are very complicated for this simple work.

Comment: A table in Libreoffice Writer?

Comment: It seems a table in libreoffice is working.Thanks

Comment: How to export it as csv?

Comment: (Tables) in LibreOffice Calc is more CVS friendly.

Comment: Ok, I think problem can be solved simply by double clicking on the cell rather than single click. Import option pop up only when pasting while selecting a cell. But if we double click it, we can paste in that cell without Import pop up.

Comment: Finally I'm using Atom with Package named tablr as a temp solution.But it don't have option to add new rows,so I have to make a blank csv file with desired no. of field seperator in each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LibreOffice Calc, press <kbd>F2</kbd> and then paste. This is similar to your answer in the comments but uses an extra keystroke instead of double-clicking.

Alternatively, a reliable 2 key combination method is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to paste unformatted.

In Writer, this can be done with a single key combination, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. However, Calc seems better suited to your needs, and this combination does not work in Calc.

Note that on Windows, no import dialog is displayed. Instead, it is pasted as HTML instead of plain text by default.